# How do I create a time range form field?

Tags: 8, datetime

Is there any way to add time range input fields in a form, for example using code similar to the following one?

```
$form['notification_hours'] = array(
  '#type' => 'time_range', // type time_range doesn't work
  '#title' => $this->t('Notification hours:'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('ecc_general.notification_hours'),
  '#description' => $this->t('what are the hours that messages should not be sent?'),
);
```

I have tried the [Time Range](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_range) and and [Time Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field) modules. I'm able to add the time range field, but I failed to programmatically create it.

Comment: Maybe the Duration Field module (http://dgo.to/duration_field)

Comment: Tried it, wasn't the one that I want :(

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but if you install [time field](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field) module you then could do this to simulate a range:

```
$form['from'] = [
  '#type' => 'time',
  '#title' => 'from',
];
$form['to'] = [
  '#type' => 'time',
  '#title' => 'to',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this creates two separate input fields, by time range field I mean both `from` and `to`  in **one** input filed.